# Android Bluetooth programming

Tags: android, bluetooth

i am writing an Android app for interfacing a Pedometer with an android application using Bluetooth. 
Here is my sample code for Bluetooth

```
package com.example.bluetooth_demo;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Simer extends ActionBarActivity {
    ArrayAdapter<String> listadapter ;
    Button connectnew;
    BluetoothAdapter btadapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simer);

        init();
        if(btadapter==null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No bluetooth", 0).show();
            finish();
        }
        else{
            if (!btadapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent turnOnIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                 startActivityForResult(turnOnIntent, 1);

                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth turned on" ,
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
              else{
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth is already on",
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }


        }

    }
private void init(){

connectnew = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btadapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

}

   }
```

it works fine till i programmed upto

```
  if(btadapter==null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No bluetooth", 0).show();
                finish();
            }
```

but when i added the following code

```
if (!btadapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Intent turnOnIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                     startActivityForResult(turnOnIntent, 1);

                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth turned on" ,
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
                  else{
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth is already on",
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
```

it didn't work. it gives an error Unfortunately app has stopped and in eclipse i got source not found.

What is the problem?
i think  if (!btadapter.isEnabled()) is creating some problem.

Comment: Set some breakpoints on "turnOnintent" and following lines, so you can see the exception. The exception is probably thrown on the startActivity line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was that i Hadn't added permissions in the manifest file for Bluetooth.after adding following lines it worked fine.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```